# Creating a table for descriptive statistics

Tags: dplyr, datatables, statistics, tidyverse, summary

im currently trying to create a table of the following variables. I have a number of countries with total sales. I would like to create table with median, mean, stdev # of products that were sold on the horizontal axes and the countries on the vertical axis.

```
          median    mean    stdev   # prod
```

nl
Us
Ca

when trying to use the summary code, I do not get the descriptives I need, and Also get them only separately, not in the form i would like to

Comment: Can you provide a full reproducible example of the data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Also you can try the `skim` function from the `skimr` package and see if that gives you what you need.

Comment: thank you very much Harrison Jones, the skimr package is great!

Answer (score 0):

dplyr is the place to go for these types of summaries

```
df <- data.frame(col_name = c(10, 22, 53, 54, 59),col_name2 = c(20, 35, 47, 533, 6))



df %>%
summarize(mean = mean(col_name),
median = median(col_name),
std = sd(col_name)  )
```